# Where should be pagination in Flux (React)?

Tags: reactjs, flux

This is flux:
[image]

So.....
The user interactions in the view should raise the Actions by using the Action Creators. The views only get updated when the Stores changed. So, lets suppose this case:

- I have a `UserStore` where there will be all information for users
- I show user's  in several places, for instances my followers, and those who I'm following
- Each of those user's collections, have a pagination, and a filter:

[image]

So, my question is, **Where should be stored the pagination and filter data???**

That information can't be in the `UserStore`, because it is a store for all users. Also, it can't be stored in the react view, because, for instance, the current page change according for instance the filter, when I star typing, a new filter is applied and the current page must become 0 (the first one), and in this case, the view need to listen for the actions, and that breaks the flux!

Note that this problem, could be even worse! Imagine that you have n-collections of users! or another items, for instance, messages of chat conversations, and each one with pagination and filter!

Comment: Create FollowersComponent store that has the current filter and the current page for that component. If your filter changes the total number of pages such that you need to change the current page, just dispatch a new action with the new current page.

Comment: And in the case of the chats example? there are n possibles lists

Comment: You don't show `n` lists all at once. You only need to contain store information for the currently displayed lists. If you display all `n` lists then you need `n` stores, because each list has its independent state.. this is the same problem whether you were using flux or not, but likely this it not the case.

Comment: Of course you could just have one store for that data, with an array of objects like `{ listId, currentFilter, currentPage }`